# Can I launch protractor mobile test on the AWS Device Farm

Tags: amazon-web-services, protractor, aws-device-farm

Can I run my e2e test developed using Protractor on the AWS device farm?

Because I want to complete mobile testing of my project using the AWS device farm, and do not really understand can I do that or not. I found 3 types about that on the AWS forum, but it is too old from 2018.

1. [First forum discussion](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=766478#766478)
2. [Second forum discussion](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=758973#758973)
3. [Third forum discussion](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=878184#878184)

Maybe something changed?

I have protractor e2e tests written for the desktop browser and want to use those ones for the mobile browser too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer this for both mobile browsers and desktop testing.

**Mobile Browsers**

AWS Device Farm has 2 execution modes: Standard Mode and Custom Mode.
Standard mode gives you granular reporting if you don't generate a report for your tests locally. This splits up the artifacts for each test.
Custom mode gives you as close as possible execution state and results as you would get locally. It does not give you the granular reporting which is fine for most as you already get reports locally which will be available on Device Farm as well. It is recommended for customers to use custom mode as that is the one that is most up to date and adds supports for latest frameworks unless of course they absolutely need granular reporting.

**Protractor on Device Farm**

It is not officially support today. 
However, Device Farm supports Appium Nodejs in custom mode. You get a yaml file where you can run shell commands on the host machine where the tests will be executed. So in case of protractor you could select this test type (Appium Nodejs), install the missing dependencies needed for the tests, start your server, and run your tests.

The points to evaluate: Since Device Farm takes your tests as inputs, you will have to upload the zip file of your tests. I would highly recommend checking the instructions for nodejs tests and using the [same](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-appium.html#test-types-appium-create-a-zip). Alternatively, you can also download your tests on the fly using the yaml file.

**Desktop Browsers**

Device Farm has a selenium grid that you can connect to from your local machine and run your tests. The browsers Chrome and Firefox run on Windows platform and Safari is not supported today. If you use a selenium grid on your local machine for your tests, then you most likely should be able to run the same tests using the Selenium grid on Device Farm. Of course, pending validation.

If you need more help on any of these items feel free to reach out to aws-devicefarm-support@amazon.com and I can help you further.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I try all works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can test in chrome with an emulated mobile mode:

You can add "mobileEmulation" in a new protractor.conf-mobile.js

```
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--disable-infobars', '--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1920,1080'],
        'mobileEmulation' : { 'deviceName': 'Galaxy S5' },
```

Comment: Good solution, but not for me. Because I need also the Firefox and Safari to be tested.